# How do I use multiple strings as keys in file renaming?

Tags: python, refactoring

Ok so I am making a file renaming program to help clean up file names. Everything seems to work how I would like it to but I have an issue that I would like to solve if possible. I want to take the cleanup section and make it more streamlined so it is not a bunch of repeated code.

This is like what I am trying to accomplish

```
for filename in os.listdir(dirName):
    if keypar, keyperiod, keydblspc in filename:  #how can I use multiple keys?  
        filepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename.replace(keypar,""))
        os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)
```

This is what I have so far its not clean but its getting there.

```py
import os
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

print("The first step will be to chooses the folder containing the files you wish to rename.\n")

print("After this selection is made the user may pick up to 3 keywords to remove from the file names. leave unneeded inputs blank and continue./n")

dirName = askdirectory() # shows dialog box and return the path
print(dirName)

keyword1 = input('Choose the first keyword would you like to remove from file names?\n')# First keyword

keyword2 = input('Choose the second keyword would you like to remove from file names?\n')# can be left blank

keyword3 = input('Choose the third keyword would you like to remove from file names?\n')# can be left blank

keypar = "()" # for clean up so you dont have to do stuff like 720 and (720) in different runs.

keyperiod = ".", keyjpg = "jpg" 

keymov = " mov" 

keymkv = " mkv" 

keygif = " gif" 

keymp4 = " mp4" 

keymp3 = " mp3" 

keydblspc = "  "

##################### Main ############################################################

for fname in os.listdir(dirName):
    if keyword1 or keyword2 or keyword3 in fname:
        print(fname, "Contains a keyword\n")

################### Keywords ##########################################################

for filename in os.listdir(dirName):
    if keyword1 in filename:    
        filepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename.replace(keyword1,""))
        os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)

for filename in os.listdir(dirName):
    if keyword2 in filename:    
        filepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename.replace(keyword2,""))
        os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)

for filename in os.listdir(dirName):
    if keyword3 in filename:    
        filepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename.replace(keyword3,""))
        os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)

################  Cleanup  ###########################################################

for filename in os.listdir(dirName):
    if keypar in filename:    
        filepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename.replace(keypar,""))
        os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)

for filename in os.listdir(dirName):
    if keyperiod in filename:    
        filepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename.replace(keyperiod,""))
        os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)


for fname in os.listdir(dirName):
   print(fname, "Has been renamed\n")
```

I was trying to use a list at first but ran into several issues but maybe I need to revisit that option. The spacing and grouping is a bit weird as well, I will correct it later.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this resolved in a different question. not exactly the answer but it accomplished what I was trying to do here in a different way. Here's the link to that one. [How do I use a list or set as keys in file renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74150605/how-do-i-use-a-list-or-set-as-keys-in-file-renaming)