# How do I use a list or set as keys in file renaming

Tags: python

Is something like this possible? Id like to use a dictionary or set as the key for my file renamer. I have a lot of key words that id like to filter out of the file names but the only way iv found to do it so far is to search by string such as `key720 = "720"` this make it functions correctly but creates bloat. I have to have a version of the code at bottom for each keyword I want to remove.

how do I get the list to work as keys in the search?
I tried to take the list and make it a string with:

```
str1 = ""
keyres = (str1.join(keys))
```

This was closer but it makes a string of all the entry's I think and didn't pick up any keywords.

so iv come to this at the moment.

```
keys = ["720p", "720", "1080p", "1080"]

for filename in os.listdir(dirName):
    if keys in filename:    
        filepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename.replace(keys,""))
        os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)
```

Is there a way to maybe go by index and increment it one at a time? would that allow the strings in the list to be used as strings?

What I'm trying to do is take a file name and rename it by removing all occurrences of the key words.

Comment: "Go by index and increment it one at a time/allow the strings in the list to be used as strings" yes, simply use a loop: `for key in keys: ...`.

Comment: I tried but got this                                                                          
for filename in os.listdir(dirName):
    for keys in keys:
        if keys in filename:    
            filepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename)
            newfilepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename.replace(keys,""))
            os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)                                                                               it would grab the first key in the list but nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Regular Expressions, specifically the sub function?

```
from re import sub

KEYS = ["720p", "720", "1080p", "1080"]

old_filename = "filename1080p.jpg"
new_filename = sub('|'.join(KEYS),'',old_filename)

print(new_filename)
```

Comment: Sweet it works now I didn't realize I could use .join on the (keywords) list like that thank you. for clarification I removed the line "if keys in filename:" and modified line                 "newfilepath = os.path.join(dirName, filename.replace(keys,""))" to                                                    "newfilepath = sub('|'.join(keywords),'',filepath)"    This seem to eliminate the need to use the list as a string as I was trying to.  Thankyou again!

Comment: I can't upvote yet sorry